# How to keep response body when MVC action returns error status?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8

I want to return `BadRequest` status and error message from my MVC controller:

```
public class TestController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    public ActionResult Bad()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 400;
        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = new { Message = "Request is bad!" },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
}
```

It works when I launch application in IISExpress, the method returns response body:

```
{"Message":"Request is bad!"}
```

But when I deploy same site to IIS (ver. 8.5) the response body changed to:

```
Bad Request
```

Why this happen? Is there some settings that allows to keep response body when status is not 200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solutions:

1. Set [Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors(v=vs.110).aspx) to true.
2. Set `existingResponse` to `PassThrough` in [httpErrors](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors)